# Fix links addresses on websites HTML code

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink

i have been working on one tool lately. It grabs all the link addresses from the website.

My problem is that links in html code sometimes is different:

- /index.php
- index.php
- http://www.website.com/index.php

I need to make all links same:

```
/index.php                       -> http://www.website.com/index.php
index.php                        -> http://www.website.com/index.php
http://www.website.com/index.php -> http://www.website.com/index.php
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using preg_replace to fix relative urls

**Requires:**
`$domain` = the subject sites domain
`$path` = the document or string you are looking for relative links with in.

**Returns:**
`$url` = the doument or string with the links within it converted to proper urls with the domain given.

**Code:**

```
$url = preg_replace('<a\shref="([\/\?\w\.=\&]+)"([\s]rel="(\w+)")*>/', '<a href="http://{$site_domain}$1" rel="$3">' $path)
```

good luck, let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to GoogleOverflow.com.

Here is the complete tutorial for parsing links in HTML using PHP and regex: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/parse-links/

Comment: Combine this with Max S's function, and you're set.

Comment: Type the 3 tags into Google and see if the question isn't answered in 0.26 seconds. The frequency with which this is the case is alarming. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a function](http://www.web-max.ca/PHP/misc_24.php) which will return the absolute URL given the base (current) URL and a relative one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for the existence of a [base](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp) tag. If you find it, it specify the base URL (otherwise, the base URL is the same path the browser points to, up to the last /).